# How to call the Javascript file inside Body tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with a popup code on a template. I am inserting Java script and HTML code in the Body of each webpage. I don't have access to the Header. I can save the codes in separate file and call it here.

I would like to write the codes in a separate file and call it in body tag.  How do I do that. Currently, both html code for popup and Javascript to open the popup on page loads, are in the body tag and working fine. I would like to keep minimal codes in the body tag. I would like to write these two set of codes in different file and call it in the body tag (btw, I have to have the cookie session code here in the body tag, since every page has different cookie name). How and what do I need to do here? Thanks!

```
<!--popup header-->
    <div  class="popUpTitle">
        <span style="float:left; font-family: Lucida Grande; font-weight: bold; font-size:24px;margin-left:9px; margin-top:5px; color:  #353535;">
             Newsletter Sign Up
         </span>
         <span onClick="closePopUp()" >
             <img alt="Close Popup" src="location/images/close.png" width="28px" height="27px"></span>
    </div>
 <!--rest of the popup information-->
```

Javascript inside body tag right after the above code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var link;
if(getCookie("was_here_before3")=="") {
setTimeout(openPopUp, 3000);
createCookie("was_here_before3", "yes");
}

function createCookie(name, value, days) {
var expires;
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 60 * 1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
}
else  {
    expires = "";
}
document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
    c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    if (c_start != -1) {
        c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
        c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1) {
            c_end = document.cookie.length;
        }
        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
    }
}
return "";
}

function openPopUp() {
element = document.getElementById("background");
element.style.display = "block";
element = document.getElementById("popup");
element.style.display = "block";
}

function closePopUp() {
element = document.getElementById("popup");
element.style.display = "none";
element = document.getElementById("background");
element.style.display = "none";
}

</script>
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: save your code in external js file and include where you're currently including just after the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to put the `<script>` in the `<head>`, you can just put it anywhere. You can do it simply by changing the `<script>` tag to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/script.js"></script>
```

There is no need to do anything else, just place the original code in the referenced file.

Comment: Yes, the code will work just like if it were inlined.

Comment: If you just need the HTML code as a template, you could do an XHR request to the server to get the template as simple text and use theElementThatPresentsTheCode.innerHTML = downloadedTemplate; to show the HTML.

Comment: As for passing parameters to the Javascript, you can use server generated js with query parameters, or to do it all client side you can use <script>window.pageName="something";</script><script src="path/to/script.js"></script> and refer to the window.pageName in the js file.

Comment: As stackoverflow doesn't like long comments and I cannot move you into chat, you can read about XHR here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: I understand and I am sorry for lengthy chat, I just found these in another post in Stackoverflow, can I use this, if so, how do I use it in body tag. Just this one please. Using jQuery:

a.html:

<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
b.html:

<p> This is my include file </p>

Comment: It is really simple. In the script file, just add this: $(function(){ $("#popupholder").load("path/to/file.html"); }); And have a div with an id="popupholder" in the place of the current bigger HTML. The script will load the HTML from the given file into that div.

Comment: This is exactly what you need to do. The thing is, there is a place in your HTML, where the popup template will load. There is a script which will load and manage the popup. There is an HTML file which contains the HTML of the popup. By using the jQuery load you've found, you can load the popup HTML into the right place easily.

Comment: <div id="popupholder"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/js/Aboutus.js">
$(function(){ $("#popupholder").load("path/popup.html"); });
</script> - I added this code in the body of Aboutus.html, but the popup not working. I created separate popup.html with the popup codes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry to trouble you, my site is down just for this work, I need to up and running for the weekend. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: You need to put the jQuery load into the Aboutus.js

Comment: I used this code. a.html:

<html> 
  <body>
  <h1>Put here your HTML content before insertion of b.js.</h1>
      ...

  <script src="b.js"></script>

      ...

  <p>And here whatever content you want afterwards.</p>
  </body>
</html>
b.js:

document.write('\
\
    <h1>Add your HTML code here</h1>\
\
     <p>Notice however, that you have to escape LF's with a '\', just like\
        demonstrated in this code listing.\
    </p>\
\
');and it works great! Thanks for your timely help! truly appreciate. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to solve it:

```
<html>
<body>
hi
<script type="text/javascript">

your javascript stuff here!

</script>
</body>
</html>
```